# Determining the spectral representation of a operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

The spectral representation for a self-adjoint operator $T \in L(H)$ for H a Hilbert space is written as:
$$
T = \sum_{\lambda \in \sigma(T)} \lambda \pi_{\lambda},
$$
where $\sigma(T)$ is the spectrum of the operator and $\pi_{\lambda}$ is the orthogonal projection on the eigenspace of $\lambda$. This definition is rather vague to me, especially the meaning of $\pi_{\lambda}$ and the way to calculate this in practice. I have been working on an example. $T: l^2 \rightarrow l^2$ defined by:
$$
T e_{2k-1} = -\frac{e_{2k}}{\sqrt{k}}
$$
$$
T e_{2k} = 2\frac{e_{2k-1}}{\sqrt{k}}.
$$
I am supposed to calculate the spectral representation of T*T. I have calculated the adjoint of T to be: $(T^*x)_{2l} = (2/\sqrt{l}) x_{2l-1}$ and $(T^*x)_{2l-1} = (-1/\sqrt{l})x_{2l}$. Now I don't have a clue how to calculate $\pi_{\lambda}$.

Comment: Have you computed $T^*T$?

Comment: Yes: $(T^*Tx)_{2k} = \frac{4x_{2k}}{k}$ and $(T^*Tx)_{2k-1} = \frac{x_{2k-1}}{k}$

Comment: So $T^*T$ is a diagonal operator.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know what that means for $\pi_{\lambda}$. Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: @Erik you already wrote that $\pi_\lambda$ is an orthgonal projection onto eigenspace of eigenvalue $\lambda$. Since $T^*T$ is  a diagonal operator it is very easy to determine its eigenvalues and eigenspaces. Even more I can say that this eqigenspacces are one dimensional.

Comment: @Norbert I find the eigenvalues $\lambda = 2/(k+1)$ for odd k with eigenvector $x=(0,0,...x_k,0,0,...)$ and the eigenvalues $\lambda = 8/k$ for even k with eigenvector $x=(0,0,...x_k,0,0,...)$. Does this mean I can write $T^*T = \sum_{k \mathrm{ even}} 8/k \pi_k + \sum_{k \mathrm{ odd}} 2/(k+1)\pi_k$ ? (With $\pi_k = <.|e_k>e_k$)

Comment: @Erik you are right

Comment: Does anyone have the solution with steps? I am struggling with a likewise problem and would greatly appreciate someone explaining how to tackle a problem like this.